# Using strcmp() in my cgi code, for an html webpage, is causing a server error

Tags: html, mysql, cgi

I am making an html webpage that uses cgi to access a table/database in mysql. I input a .csv file containing info on my class schedule and the html displays it in the usual schedule table.

My problem is that I can't seem to use strcmp in my parsing cgi as it causes a server error. here is an excerpt of my code where I uses strcmp.

```
void parse2(char *queu)
{
//---------------------------------------------------------------
    char *saveptr[1024];
    char *subtoken;
    char *Subject;
    char *Day;
    char *Start;
    char *End;
    char *Room;
    char *Teacher;
    int check = 1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------
    subtoken = strtok_r(queu, ",", saveptr);

    check = strcmp(subtoken, "\0");
    printf("%d<br>", check);

    if(check == 0){
        printf("Error!");
    } else {
        Subject = subtoken;
        Day = strtok_r(NULL, ",", saveptr);
        Start = strtok_r(NULL, ",", saveptr);
        End = strtok_r(NULL, ",", saveptr);
        Room = strtok_r(NULL, ",", saveptr);
        Teacher = strtok_r(NULL, ",", saveptr);

        printf("%s\n<br/>%s\n<br/>%s\n<br/>%s\n<br/>%s\n<br/>%s\n", Subject, Day, Start, End, Room, Teacher);

        //inputsql(Subject, Day, Start, End, Room, Teacher);
    }   
//---------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Note that, I have tested this code and it works fine without me calling `strcmp()`.

I am using `strcmp()` to prevent a line of unwanted characters, generated after the info when retrieved using `POST` method, from being entered into my database.

As you can see from the above code, I used `strtok()` to parse the line of info. Since the line of unwanted characters do not contain a comma (which is my delimiter) it should return a NULL value. correct?

Can anyone help me out? I welcome suggestions to use a different way on solving the problem I chose to solve using `strcmp()`.

Comment: what that error is saying?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be checking `subtoken == NULL`, not `strcmp(subtoken, "\0") == 0`.

`"\0"` is a string containing a NUL byte, then another NUL (the terminator), so the standard library's string functions will just see an empty string. That's different to a NULL pointer (i.e. a pointer with value zero).

From [`STRTOK(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html):

```
   Each call to strtok() returns a pointer to a null-terminated string
   containing the next token.  This string does not include the
   delimiting byte.  If no more tokens are found, strtok() returns NULL.
```